# Event invoke in constructor

Tags: c#

I need to subscribe an event that invokes at constructor

I tried `_eventCaller = new EventCaller().Event += EventVoid;`, but it doesn't work

I am asking you to suggest me other solutions for this code, but not make THIS code work

Here is the simplified code with edited names I'm using:

```
private class EventCaller
{
    public delegate void EventDelegate();

    public event EventDelegate Event;

    public EventCaller()
    {
        Event?.Invoke();
    }
}

private class EventSubscriber
{
    private EventCaller _eventCaller;

    private void Subscribe()
    {
        _eventCaller = new EventCaller();
        _eventCaller.Event += EventVoid;
    }


    private void EventVoid()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It doesn't work

Comment: Atr the time the constructor runs, the event handler isn't attached. Note that you suscribe to it **after** the constructor returned.

Comment: This smells like something you shouldn't do... Besides I don't think it is possible

Comment: Your question is unclear. It is not possible for client code to subscribe to an event of a class it's instantiating until the constructor has finished. Why would a constructor be implemented to raise an event, without making accommodation for the caller passing an event handler to the constructor? Please improve the question so that it's clear how you got into this situation and what solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Well, "It is not possible for client code to subscribe to an event of a class it's instantiating until the constructor has finished" is not *precisely* true.  Code earlier in the constructor could have resulting in adding a handler (perhaps via a callback).  But that certainly is not happening in this simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just passing the `EventDelegate` to `EventCaller` ctor? Like this:

```
private class EventCaller
{
    public delegate void EventDelegate();

    public event EventDelegate Event;

    public EventCaller(EventDelegate ev)
    {
        Event += ev;
        Event?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

And in `EventSubscriber`:

```
private class EventSubscriber
{
    ...
    public void Subscribe()
    {
        _eventCaller = new EventCaller(EventVoid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this before, but probably something I was doing wrong

Comment: @ПегасЕвгений was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you need a common `Event` happening when a new object of `EventCaller` is created.

```
private class EventCaller
{
    public delegate void EventDelegate();

    public static event EventDelegate Event;

    public EventCaller()
    {
        Event?.Invoke();
    }
}

private class EventSubscriber
{
    private EventCaller _eventCaller;

    static EventSubscriber() 
    {
        EventCaller.Event += EventVoid
    }
    
    private void Subscribe()
    {
        _eventCaller = new EventCaller();
    }
    
    private static void EventVoid()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```